# Phpstorm. Can't access to mysql server through SSH tunnel (connection is closed by foreign host)

Tags: mysql, ssh, intellij-idea, phpstorm, mariadb

Sorry for the mistakes I've made, I'm not Englishman.

I use vagrant to deploy remote virtual machine as my web server which is configured to use `:private_network, ip: "192.168.10.10"`. On the machine is installed Nginx, PHP, MariaDB etc.

Recently, I start to use phpstorm as my main IDE. Now I'm trying to configure access to remote database server, but I fail. Please, see the screens for additional information.

To check the ssh and mysql server access I tried the following:

```
$ ssh vagrant@192.168.10.10 #ok
$ mysql -h localhost -P 3306 -u root -p #ok (it's run on the remote machine)
$ telnet -l root localhost 3306 #also run on the remote machine,
the output:
5.5.5-10.0.7-MariaDB-1~precise-log%how)b3s?�O|G*=63=yi#qmysql_native_password
Connection closed by foreign host.
```

MariaDB configuration file seems to be ok. I only changed `bind-address` in `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` to `0.0.0.0`.

I tried to set different configuration data, like: localhost:8080 instead of 169.168.10.10:80, double check password in SSH tunnel window, but nothing. Please, help me..

[image][image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In my case I had to enable TCP forwarding in the ssh configuration of the remote host:

```
AllowTCPForwarding yes
```

And also I had to grant all privileges on users connection from 127.0.0.1 (instead of just from 'locahost'):

```
grant all privileges on some_db.* to some_user@127.0.0.1 identified by 'secret';
```

Comment: I can't check this answer now, but still) just thanks)

Answer (score 3):

You don't **have** to use the Vagrantfile for port forwarding, vagrant will take care of it itself. In this case, once the VM is up and running (using *vagrant up*) use the command *vagrant ssh-config* to ascertain which SSH port you should use, as running multiple VMs will mean port clashes (which vagrant takes care of, but you may not be aware of which port to use).

In PHPStorm 6 to connect to a vagrant hosted VM's MariaDB/MySQL, open the Database Window (**View** > **Tool Windows** > **Database**) and add a **MySQL** connection using the wizard. The trick is what to put in where.

If it helps, permit me to explain in full how I connect, using an identity file (also shown in the *vagrant ssh-config* utility):

1. Ensure that the VM has AllowTCPForwarding (as mentioned above) set up in */etc/ssh/sshd_config* and that the ssh service has been restarted, or the VM rebooted since that change was made
2. Once the VM is up and running, run *vagrant ssh-config*
3. Note the Port number
4. Note the IdentityFile being used

Once you have that, start PHPStorm, open your project and then the database window (**View** > **Tool Windows** > **Database**). You've probably already got a connection listed, but if not, click on the **+** icon, then **Data Source** > **MySQL**.

When the Data Sources and Drivers dialogue box opens, complete as outlined below:

**General Tab**

- Host : 127.0.0.1
- Port : 3306
- Database : Name of database required to connect to
- User : the MariaDB/MySQL user you'd normally connect with
- Password : the MariaDB/MySQL users password

**SSH/SSL Tab**

- Use SSH tunnel : enabled
- Proxy host : 127.0.0.1 (typically it's 127.0.0.1 but you can confirm this as it's outlined in ssh-config's *HostName*)
- Port : (as outlined in ssh-config's *Port*)
- Proxy user : (the name of the account that you'd normally use to SSH into the VM with. *Typically* this is "vagrant" for vagrant boxes)
- Auth type: Key pair (OpenSSH)
- Private key file : (the path ssh-config's IdentityFile)

If you understand that the SSH connection is handled first, and then the database connection, then the settings start to make a little more sense. For example, you'll note that **nowhere** do you have to type in the IP of the vagrant box itself, that's all handled through vagrant's (automatic) port forwarding.

Comment: I was indeed providing wrong `Private key file : (the path ssh-config's IdentityFile)`, fixing that it fixed my connection problem. Thank you for the detailed step by step answer.

Comment: **ERROR:** `Base64-encoded string must have at least four characters, but length specified was 3.`

Answer (score 1):

you must forward the ssh port (22) by editing `Vagrantfile`

```
config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 22, host: 22
```

and `Reload` vagrant box.

then you go to the `SSH/SSL` tunnel tab and check `Use SSH tunnel`

```
Proxy host: localhost
Proxy user: vagrant
Auth type: Password
password: vagrant
```

Then go back to `Database` tab and hit `Test Connection`!!!

Comment: does not work anymore

Answer (score 0):

Solved! The problem was incorrect port. Use your vagrant IP and port 22, or (localhost|127.0.0.1) and port 2222.